# Why am I getting black background when displaying a list-view icon?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, common-controls

I'm not sure why I'm getting this black outline when I add an icon to the CListCtrl (or list-view control)?

[image]

I load it as such:

```
//HICON hIcon;
LoadIconWithScaleDown(theApp.m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(Icon_ID), 15, 15, &hIcon);
```

I then create my image list as such:

```
//CImageList iml;
iml.Create(15, 15, ILC_COLOR32, numberIcons, 0);
iml.Add(hIcon);
```

the list view is prepped first:

```
//CListCtrl lst;
lst.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | 
    LVS_EX_LABELTIP | LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP | LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES);
lst.ModifyStyle(0, LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS);
```

and the icon is displayed in the subitem of the list as such:

```
int nInd = lst.InsertItem(c, L"Main label");

lst.SetItem(nInd, nSubitemIndex, LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE, L"2 files", nIconInd, 0, 0, 0);
```

So what am I doing wrong?

PS. I ran this test on my Windows 8.1 with a 32-bit trucolor display setting.

The icon itself though is a 256-color image since I don't see any reason to waste space on a 32-bit icon with an alpha channel for such a small size & simple design:

[image]

Comment: since you have a white background you can just put the white color in there, but I believe you need an alpha channel if you want a transparency there

Comment: _" I don't see any reason to waste space on a 32-bit icon"_ - Is the time you're wasting on this problem really worth a saving few hundred bytes?

Comment: The background depends on the user selection in CP. So it will not be necessarily white. As for adding alpha-channel icons -- it then looks OK on Win 8.1 but when I load the app in an older XP machine with a 16-bit color scheme, it still shows the black background. Plus I don't have just 1 icon. It's way more than that.

Comment: You configured the image list for 32 bit color with alpha and then supplied an image with no alpha. Supply an image with alpha and it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` has [transparency issues on XP](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/700290/), you are likely encountering that.  You may have to owner-draw the images onto the list view to preserve the transparency.  Or, load the images into one image list, then render a copy of the images with a background color matching the list view's color to a separate image list, and then use the second image list with the list view.

Comment: @c00000fd: Yes, XP doesn't deal with transparency really well. If I were you I'd render _all_ of your list-views as custom-drawn. It's not that difficult. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra) a nice sample code that shows how to do it right.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to XP. And XP handles transparency fine. Owner draw is certainly not needed here.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe water under the bridge by now, but I found colordepth settings of 8 bit on my offending imagelist. Setting it to 32 resulted in transpareency working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread here
[Getting alpha blending to work with CImageList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097312/getting-alpha-blending-to-work-with-cimagelist)

Adding this line one C++ file did the trick:

```
enter code here
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Do not even ask... but it took me a long time to find that out

Comment: Thanks. I can't confirm nor deny if it solves the issue. It's been awhile since I messed with it.